# alert button that displays currently selected value of a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a button that gives the user the option to view a description through an alert message/window. I try to do this by reading the id of the `<select>` field (keep in mind this will not be the only `<select>` tag on the page) and use its value to display the info I want.

At the moment I am only testing to see if the value is being read. Which is a failure.

**JavaScript Code**

```
`function displayInfo() {
    var value = $'#soup :selected').val();
    alert(value);
}`
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="BOX2" style="display: none">
<select name="soup" id="soup">
    <option></option>
        <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survival_mode.soup_t");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value=\"{$row['soup_ID']}\">";
            echo $row['soup_name']."</option><br />";
        }
        echo "\n";
        ?>
</select>
<input type="button" value="view"
    onclick="displayInfo();" />
</div>
```

Comment: `$'#soup :selected').val();` needs to be `$('#soup :selected').val();`

Comment: Don't use `<br />` inside a select element.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need is :

```
var $soup = $('#soup');

$soup.next().on('click', function() {
    var val = $soup.val();
    alert( val );
});
```

The select will have the same value as the selected option, and no inline event handlers are needed.

Giving the button an ID would make it a little cleaner.

Comment: How would giving the button an ID make this process cleaner?

Comment: @user2337345 - Elements with ID could be targeted directly without the need for next(), and it would be faster.

Comment: So if I gave the button an id called `display` the new line would look like `$soup.display.on('click', function() {`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to filter it by the selected attribute. Just calling the val() method on the dropdown selector will give you the selected value in the dropdown.

```
function displayInfo() {
   var value = $('#soup').val();
   alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to submit the form first to be able to use the $('id') action?

Comment: As I understand from the code snippet you provided, the dropdown is populated when the page is loaded, and when you click on the button, you need the value that was selected in the dropdown. Once the HTML (in this case, the dropdown) has been added to the DOM, you can access the  element using it's ID. HTH.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm doing and would like to do. I have been able to access the data, but it will only give me the first options value. For example if the first option is `<option></option>` then the value is null. But if the first option was like this `<option value="CT-TX">Something</option>` then that is the value the javascript reads. When I go to change the selection in the interface drop down, this value doesn't change to the corresponding one.

Comment: **code**
`function displayInfo(content) {
 var currentSelect = document.getElementById(content).value;
 
 alert(currentSelect);
}`

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but I'm able to get the selected value. Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G56Dy/1/). Can you check what is the HTML output once the page is run? Maybe it is something in that.

Comment: Yes I see the html output but when I select a value then click `view` nothing pops up. Could it be that my browser is the issue?